# Angular ui.router infinite loop on $state or $location change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, eventemitter

I am at the end of my wits, nerves, everything, for the past 4 hours I am TRYING to debug and reading all over the internet what the problem might be with this.

So, I am working on mocking up a mobile application and my logic is like this:

1. If the user has logged in the past, we have data in localStorage about that, then show him the listing. this is offline
2. If we are connected to the internet, show the listing first and in the background check to see if he is still logged in
3. If HE ISN'T, redirect to login page.

On the main Home view, I am evaluating the above statements, first I show him the listing if he has localStorage data, then I check online and redirect to login if necessary.

Whenever I have two $state or $locations it **loops**. Like the browser almost freezes, lucky it's Chrome. and I get the `Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null`. From what I read, a known angular.ui router issue, if used bad or some other mystical problem.

Some Code:

These event emitters and receivers, which I call in the return of my StateManagement Services

```
//Notification Helpers, also exposed, to keep them in the same scope tree.
        function emitNotification (event, data) {
            console.log('Emitting event: ' + event);
            $rootScope.$emit(event, data);

        }

        function emitListen (event, fn) {
            console.log('Listening for: ' + event);
            $rootScope.$on(event, function (e, data) {
                fn(data);
            });

        }
```

.
.
.LOGIC

```
//Update the userData in localStorage and in .value
                                $auth.storage.set('userData', data);
                                userData = $auth.storage.get('userData'); //TODO: Redundant, store it directly, is it ok?

                                emitNotification('event:auth-okServer', data);
                                //return 'ok-server';
```

... return my service

```
},
            loginSuccess: function(data){
                emitNotification('event:auth-loginSuccess', data);
            },
            loginFailed: function(data){
                emitNotification('event:auth-loginFailed', data);
            },
            notify: emitNotification,
            listen: emitListen
```

And this is in my controller:

```
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('sidemenu.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'topView': {
                        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.list', {
                url: '/list',
                templateUrl: 'home/home-list.tpl.html',
                controller: 'ListCtrl'
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'home/home-login.tpl.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: 'home/home-register.tpl.html',
                controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
            })
            .state('sidemenu.home.coach', {
                url: '/coach',
                templateUrl: 'home/home-coach.tpl.html',
                controller: 'CoachCtrl'
            })
            ;
    })

    .controller('HomeCtrl', function HomeController($scope, $state, $location, localState) {

        /**
         * EVENT EMITTERS
         * @event:auth-loginSuccess - Login has been succesfull, let everybody know.
         * @event:auth-loginFailed  - Login has failed, do something.
         * @event:auth-okServer     - Server challenge ok, user is logged in.
         * @event:auth-okLocal      - Local challenge ok, user appears to be logged in.
         * @event:auth-login        - Go to login
         * @event:general-coach     - Start the coach
         **/


        /**
         * ===== FIRST LOGIC =====
         **/


        //We are placing emitters in the same children-parent tree scope, the one from localState, and we're listening to them.
        localState.listen('event:auth-okLocal', function(data) {
            console.log('EVENT: auth-okLocal has been triggered');
            //$state.transitionTo('sidemenu.home.list');
            $location.path('/sidemenu/home/list');
            //First we will be redirected on listpage
        });

        localState.listen('event:auth-login', function() {
            console.log('EVENT: auth-login has been triggered');
            $location.path('/sidemenu/home/login');
        });
        //Server check fails, redirect to login
        localState.listen('event:general-coach', function(data) {
            console.log('EVENT: general-coach has been triggered');
            //$state.transitionTo('sidemenu.home.coach');
            $location.path('/sidemenu/home//coach');
        });

        //After we have all the listeners in place do the checking & broadcasting.
        localState.check();
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have debugged the emitters, my check() function which creates all the emitters, I have tried several combinations on ui.router and I have miserably failed :).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the same use-case, it is a bug with ui router, but waiting for it to finish the state change before transitioning solved it:

`if (webAPIAuth.isLoggedIn()) {
          $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
               $state.go('dashboard');
          });
     }`

Comment: Well, I guessed at some point that there was some sort of unfinished business in the ui.router's state, and that's why I tried running the second trasitionTo/go to the login page 3 seconds later, it does exactly the same thing, I honestly think its an unfortunate combination. As an IDEA, could I hook the event listener that listens for `event:auth-login` after the successful firing of the `'$stateChangeSuccess'` on the listing page?

Comment: No, that's still not ok, listing page will be accessed a lot. What I actually noticed is that the url in my page changes like mad from listing to login, I mean that a actual abstract redirect loop. There should be a way to chain events, when two particular events fire then then should it take me to the login page, but I in a bit of mist regarding this. :)

Comment: I just realized something, I kept on debugging the issue and I got to the conclusion that ui.router doesn't `like` other events in the same controller/etc, I mean if I delete the event listener and place button I can switch states fine, if I get all the state.go's out the listeners and I TRIGGER THEM MANUALLY, it still WON'T WORK. Only if I remove any other event listeners....  This is messed up. :(

Comment: Even though this solution works, I can still see the URL changed, and, the event is called multiple times.